# Count number of files in each subfolder, ignoring files with certain name

Tags: powershell

Consider the following directory tree

```
ROOT
    BAR001
        foo_1.txt
        foo_2.txt
        foo_ignore_this_1.txt
    BAR001_a
        foo_3.txt
        foo_4.txt
        foo_ignore_this_2.txt
        foo_ignore_this_3.txt
    BAR001_b
        foo_5.txt
        foo_ignore_this_4.txt
    BAR002
        baz_1.txt
        baz_ignore_this_1.txt
    BAR002_a
        baz_2.txt
        baz_ignore_this_2.txt
    BAR002_b
        baz_3.txt
        baz_4.txt
        baz_5.txt
        baz_ignore_this_3.txt
    BAR002_c
        baz_ignore_this_4.txt
    BAR003
        lor_1.txt
```

The structure will always be like this, so no deeper subfolders. I'm working on a script to count the number of files:

- for each BARXXX folder
- for each BARXXX_Y folder
- textfiles with "ignore_this" in the name, should be ignored in the count

For the example above, this would result into:

```
Folder      Filecount
---------------------
BAR001      2
BAR001_a    2
BAR001_b    1

BAR002      1
BAR002_a    1
BAR002_b    3
BAR002_c    0

BAR003      1
```

I now have:

```
Function Filecount {
    param(
        [string]$dir
    )
    $childs = Get-ChildItem $dir | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}

    Foreach ($childs in $child) {
        Write-Host (Get-ChildItem $dir | Measure-Object).Count;
    }
}


Filecount -dir "C:\ROOT"
```

(Not ready yet but building) This however, does not work. `$child` seems to be empty. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You've got the ForEach Syntax backwards, change it to `ForEach ($child in $childs)`.  I'm working on the full approach to give you the folder name and count too.

Comment: I've completed my response, there is now a working -IgnoreMe parameter you can use to specify a wildcard exclusion, so "*_*" would remove files with an underscore, while still returning a file count and so forth.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start, you're running `ForEach ($childs in $child)`, this syntax is backwards, so that will cause you some issues!  If you swap it, so that you're running:

```
ForEach ($child in $childs)
```

You'll get the following output:

```
>2
>2
>1
>1
>1
>3
>0
```

---

Alright, I'm back now with the completed answer.  For one, instead of using Write-Out, I'm using a PowerShell custom object to let PowerShell do the hard work for me.  I'm setting FolderName equal to the $child.BaseName, and then running a GCI on the $Child.FullName to get the file count.  I've added an extra parameter called $ignoreme, that should have an asterisk value for the values you want to ignore.

Here's the complete answer now.  Keep in mind that my file structure was a bit different than yours, so my file count is different at the bottom as well.

```
Function Filecount {
param(
    [string]$dir="C:\TEMP\Example",
    [string]$ignoreme = "*_*"
)
$childs = Get-ChildItem $dir | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}

Foreach ($child in $childs) {
        [pscustomobject]@{FolderName=$child.Name;ItemCount=(Get-ChildItem $child.FullName | ? Name -notlike $ignoreme | Measure-Object).Count}

    }
}


>Filecount | ft -AutoSize

>FolderName ItemCount
>---------- ---------
>BAR001             2
>BAR001_A           1
>BAR001_b           2
>BAR001_C           0
>BAR002             0
>BAR003             0
```

If you're using PowerShell v 2.0, use this method instead.

```
Function Filecount {
param(
    [string]$dir="C:\TEMP\Example",
    [string]$ignoreme = "*_*"
)
$childs = Get-ChildItem $dir | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}

Foreach ($child in $childs) {
    $ObjectProperties = @{
        FolderName=$child.Name
        ItemCount=(Get-ChildItem $child.FullName | ? Name -notlike $ignoreme | Measure-Object).Count}
    New-Object PSObject -Property $ObjectProperties
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, and it works like a charm on my Windows 8 machine, but it does not work as expected on my server (which runs PS 2). The code is `Function Filecount {
    param
    (
        [string]$dir,
        [string]$ignore
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Folder = $_.Name;
            Items  = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude "*$ignore*" -Path $_.FullName).count
        }
    }
}


Filecount -dir "C:\ROOT" -ignore "translated_by" | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: The result is like `Name   Value                   
----   -----                   
Items  260                     
Folder TEXT0001                
Items  14                      
Folder TEXT0001_skip           
Items  143                     
Folder TEXT0001_trans1_exported
Items                          
Folder TEXT0001_trans2_exported
Items  81                      
Folder TEXT0001_trans3_exported
Items                          
Folder TEXT0001_trans4_exported` @1RedOne Any way to make it backwards compatible?

Comment: The syntax for [pscustomobject] was introduced in PowerShell version 3.0.  If you're using PowerShell v 2.0, then just replace the whole ForEach block with this.  

E: placed within my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question however: if I run this in V3, The table from left to right has the columns `FolderName ItemCount` but running the same in V2 outputs the table as `Itemcount Foldername` ?! Putting the Itemcount in the line above Foldername in the $ObjectProperties in the script does not change this. What is causing this behavior? BTW Is it me or are the differences between V2 and V3 just very annoying? V2: `Format-Table -Auto`, V3: `Format-Table -AutoSize` Sigh :-)

Comment: It's the differences between v2 and v3. Custom Objects and hash tables would not remember sort preference in v2, which was pretty irritating.  The fix?  Upgrade to v3!  It's support even on Server 2003 these days!

Comment: Unfortunately, have to deal with an environment where I have no control over. Anyway, thanks for all your responses!

Answer (score 1):

I like that way of creating an object [1RedOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238413/1redone), haven't seen that before, thanks.

We can improve the performance of the code in a few of ways. By using the [Filter Left](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.windowspowershell.aspx) principle, which states that the provider for any cmdlet is inherently more efficient than running things through PowerShell, by performing fewer loops and by removing an unnecessary step:

```
    Function Filecount
{
    param
    (
        [string]$dir = ".",
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ignoreme
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $dir | ForEach-Object `
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{FolderName=$_.Name;ItemCount=(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude "*$ignoreme*" -Path $_.FullName).count}
    }
}
```

So, firstly we can use the -Directory switch of Get-Childitem in the top-level directory (I know this is available in v3.0 and above, not sure about v2.0).

Then we can pipe the output of this directly in to the next loop, without storing it first.

Then we can replace another `Where-Object` with a provider `-Exclude`.

Finally, we can remove the `Measure-Object` as a simple count of the array will do:

```
Filecount "ROOT" "ignore_this" | ft -a

FolderName ItemCount
---------- ---------
BAR001             2
BAR001_a           2
BAR001_b           1
BAR002             1
BAR002_a           1
BAR002_b           3
BAR002_c           0
BAR003             1
```

Cheers Folks!

Comment: Very nice, I was afraid that using -Exclude would omit the folders as well, but it seems to not work that way.

Comment: Interestingly, I had that problem at first, but it was rectified by using the -Recurse