# Counting number of files in dir returns 0 when there is only 1 file match?

Tags: powershell

Referring to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328110), I am in need of a script to count the number of:

- regular textfiles
- textfiles with a certain string in the name

The example directory structure would be like this:

```
ROOT
    BAR001
        foo_1.txt
        foo_2.txt
        foo_ignore_this_1.txt
    BAR001_a
        foo_3.txt
        foo_4.txt
        foo_ignore_this_2.txt
        foo_ignore_this_3.txt
    BAR001_b
        foo_5.txt
        foo_ignore_this_4.txt
    BAR002
        baz_1.txt
        baz_ignore_this_1.txt
    BAR002_a
        baz_2.txt
        baz_ignore_this_2.txt
    BAR002_b
        baz_3.txt
        baz_4.txt
        baz_5.txt
        baz_ignore_this_3.txt
    BAR002_c
        baz_ignore_this_4.txt
    BAR003
        lor_1.txt
```

The structure will always be like this, so no deeper subfolders. Because I am restricted to using PS 2, I now have:

```
Function Filecount {
    param
    (
        [string]$dir
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object {
        $Properties = @{
            "Last Modified" = $_.LastWriteTime
            "Folder Name"   = $_.Name;
            Originals       = [int](Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude "*_ignore_this_*" -Path $_.FullName).count
            Ignored    = [int](Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*_ignore_this_*" -Path $_.FullName).count
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
    }
}
```

The output is like this (Last Modified not filled in):

```
Folder Name      Last Modified    Originals    Ignored
-----------      -------------    ---------    -------
BAR001                                    2          1
BAR001_a                                  2          2
BAR001_b                                  0          0 <------- ??
BAR002                                    0          0 <------- ??
BAR002_a                                  0          0 <------- ??
BAR002_b                                  3          1
```

**The problem is** that the whenever there is 1 textfile and 1 "ignore" textfile in a directory, the script lists 0 for both columns instead of 1. I have no clue why. Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the return from `Get-ChildItem` an array, so that it will have `.count` property even if it only returns 1 object:

```
Function Filecount {
    param
    (
        [string]$dir
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object {
        $Properties = @{
            "Last Modified" = $_.LastWriteTime
            "Folder Name"   = $_.Name;
            Originals       = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude "*_ignore_this_*" -Path $_.FullName).count
            Ignored         = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*_ignore_this_*" -Path $_.FullName).count
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, but I fail to see why. In my version, I count the number of files in a folder using `cgi` and cast the result as a number. I agree that in doing so, the `.count` property (method?) is not available. But if `cgi` returns say `128` files, the script outputted `128` (even though `128.count` doesnt make sense). But why didn't this work for a folder with 1 file? Basically it woud return `[int]1.count` which should still be `1`, right? Why did my script work for all number of files in a folder, but not for 1?

Comment: This is a consequence of the way Powershell handles the return from an expression.  If the result is a scalar (single object), then the result will be one object of that type.  If it is returns more than one object, then Powershell will automatically package them up into an array.  A single file object does not have a .count property, so checking it returns $null.  If you cast that is [int] it results in 0.